# How do you check whether all descendants are clean (not invalidated) in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

Suppose I have an observer in Shiny like the following:

```
observe({
  input$obs_1
  input$obs_2
  input$obs_3

  # do "something"
  # ...
  # ...

  # If the code above finished doing "something," set a reactive value
  rv$something_is_done <- FALSE
  rv$something_is_done <- TRUE
})
```

The observer above will do "something" every time `obs_1`, `obs_2`, or `obs_3` changes.

**How can I check whether all of the inputs have finished changing, and the `do something` code block has run its course for the last time?**

Once the observer above returns to "idle" (goes back to listening on the three inputs), I want the reactive value at the end, `rv$something_is_done`, to trigger "another thing" to happen as a result, maybe with something like below:

```
observe({
  rv$something_is_done
  if(rv$something_is_done) {
    # do "another thing"
    # ...
    # ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observers are listening to the changes all the time. Given that you have preset values in the `obs_1, obs_2,...` it only pays attention to those. So it doesn't know or cares if you consider other 2 inputs to wait for the change or not. What you can do is to delay that reaction with `debounce` if you want like so. Note that its set to 3 seconds wait after all the params were set. I have added the 3 variables into a list so you can use it later on as `mystuff_d()`

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("obs_1", "obs_1", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),
    sliderInput("obs_2", "obs_2", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),
    sliderInput("obs_3", "obs_3", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
)

rv <- reactiveValues(something_is_done <- FALSE)

server <- function(input,output,session){

    mystuff <- eventReactive(c(input$obs_1,input$obs_2,input$obs_3),{
        rv$something_is_done <- FALSE
        c(input$obs_1,input$obs_2,input$obs_3)
    },ignoreInit = TRUE)

    mystuff_d <- mystuff %>% debounce(3000)

    observeEvent(mystuff_d(),{
        print(mystuff_d())
        # do "something"
        # ...
        # ...
        rv$something_is_done <- TRUE
    })

    observeEvent(rv$something_is_done,{
       if(rv$something_is_done){
           # do "another thing"
           # ...
           # ...
           print("another thing")
       }
    },ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  With your solution, if each input changes once, `rv$something_is_done` will toggle from `FALSE` to `TRUE` a total of 3 times right?  Is there a way to toggle the reactive value only **once**, only after all inputs finished changing?

Comment: Easier to add a button then

Comment: @johnc see example with `debounce`

Comment: @johnc see another approach

Comment: Pork Chop, your earlier answer worked exactly as I hoped!!  This problem wasted hours and hours of my time, and it looks like the `debounce` was the way to go.  You'd think Shiny would have a simpler solution for something like this.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sure np, post it here it will be answered fast enough. It's important for some components to be `stateless` where a lot of `waiting` can be covered on the dev side such s introducing temp variables into the code